# Finding age from Date of Birth in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I've searched high and low, and cannot find an answer.

Situation: I have a spreadsheet with dates of birth in column D.  I want to calculate the age of each person and put that age in column E.  I want to be able to do this for the entire spreadsheet.

```
import openpyxl as op
import datetime

for row in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    ws["D"] = ws["D" + str(row)].value
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(ws["D"], "%m/%d/%y")
    ws["E" + str(row)].value = today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

When I try to run that code block, I get

```
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'
```

which references the datetime.datetime.strptime call

The code is pretty messy at this point, because I've tried a bunch of different things and can't get it to work.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using python for this?  Seems a lot simpler to just do `(NOW() - <birthday cell>) / 365` in Excel.

Comment: Yes.  This is one step in a long process that I'm trying to automate as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The thing which you have done wrong is that you have changed the type of ws to dict in `ws["D"] = ws["D" + str(row)].value`.
What you can do is as follows

```
import openpyxl as op
import datetime

for row in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    wsx["D"] = ws["D" + str(row)].value
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(wsx["D"], "%m/%d/%y")
    ws["E" + str(row)].value = today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  However, when running the program:

    `wsx["D"] = ws["D" + str(row)].value`


returns `NameError: name 'wsx' is not defined`